# control the order of bars in a barchart using R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using R, I want bars in a bar chart in a certain order.

The order is:

```
a<-c("no exercise", "strength", "moderate aerobics", "moderate aerobics + strength", "high aerobics")
```

And then the values, let's just say:

```
b<- c(10, 20, 25, 40, 40)
df<-data.frame(a, b)
```

When creating a bar plot, the order of bars is alphabetic, rather than the original:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar( aes(x=a, y=b), stat="identity", fill="red")
```

[enter image description here][1]
Is there a way to change that?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZDXc.png## Heading ##

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to reorder it in the same order of occurence, use `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values of the column (here, we have only `unique` values but we use `unique` as a general case where the `unique` will get the unique values on the order of its occurrence)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  mutate(a = factor(a, levels = unique(a))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
     geom_bar(aes(x = a, y = b), stat = 'identity', fill = 'red')
```